# dovecot: auth: Fatal: Unknown passdb driver 'mysql'

Tags: postfix, dovecot

guys!
I have already installed dovecot-mysql mysql-devel. why did my dovecot logs keep telling me : auth: Fatal: Unknown passdb driver 'mysql' ~~~~
 Does anyone has any idea what I can do to fix this ?
  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misconfigured `passdb` and `userdb` sections of the `dovecot` config:

Place

```
driver = sql
```

instead of

```
driver = mysql
```

Comment: I used rpm package.[root@mail-esxi conf.d]# /usr/sbin/dovecot --build-options
Build options: ioloop=epoll notify=inotify ipv6 openssl io_block_size=8192
Mail storages: cydir maildir mbox mdbox raw sdbox shared
SQL driver plugins: mysql postgresql sqlite
Passdb: checkpassword ldap pam passwd passwd-file shadow sql
Userdb: checkpassword ldap(plugin) nss passwd prefetch passwd-file sql

Comment: It has been compiled with mysql support. @Kondybas

Comment: I've change my answer